# set model values from json in nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi Guys I want to know how to save json string into mongoose model object?
let me explain a simplified version of my problem:

I have a schema model:

```
const mongo = require('mongoose');
const clientSchema = mongo.Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    age: {type: Number},
    updated_at: {type: Date},
}
```

and I have a put method which is shown below:

```
var Client = mongo.model('client', clientSchema);

//Update User
server.put(`/api/clients/:_id`, (req, res) =>
{
    Client.model.findById(req.params._id, (err, foundedclient) => 
    {
        if(err) res.send(err);

        //***********************************************************//
        /*I want to update foundedclient from req.body here!         */
        /*some function like : foundedclient.JsonTovalues(req.body); */  
        //***********************************************************//

        foundedclient.updated_at = new Date().toISOString();

        foundedclient.save((err) =>
        {
            res.send('saved successfully!');
        });
      });
});
```

the `req.body` is a json:

```
{
    "name":"bardia",
    "age":27,
}
```

I want to update `foundedclient` value from `req.body` at the position I highlighted in the code by `//*******//` signs. I want a hypothetical function such as `foundedclient.JsonTovalues(req.body)`. what is the best way to achieve that? In other words what is the best way to save `json` as mode values?

Thank a lot

Comment: Why is req.body JSON *string*? It should be an object if you set up body parser correctly.

Comment: It is JSON object indeed. my question is how can I assign its values to my client values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can define an instance method to something similar to **updateByJson** as explained below

```
const clientSchema = mongo.Schema({
   name: {type: String},
   age: {type: Number},
   updated_at: {type: Date},
}

// here simply calling update method internally but exposed as an instance method 
clientSchema.methods.updateByJson = function(jsonToUpdate, cb){
   // will work if you are using mongoose old version 3.x
   this.constructor.update({_id: this._id}, {$set:jsonToUpdate}, cb);
   // should work with latest versions
   this.model('client').update({_id: this._id}, {$set:jsonToUpdate}, cb);
}
```

Your client code will look like this

```
var Client = mongo.model('client', clientSchema);

//Update User
server.put(`/api/clients/:_id`, (req, res) =>
{
    Client.model.findById(req.params._id, (err, foundedclient) => 
    {
        if(err) res.send(err);

        jsonToUpdate = req.body
        jsonToUpdate.updated_at = new Date().toISOString();

        foundedclient.updateByJson(jsonToUpdate, (err) => {
            res.send('saved successfully!');
        });
      });
});
```

I hope this helps you.